# Removing duplicates from a data frame, very fast

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a data.frame with 50,000 rows, with some duplicates, which I would like to remove.

```
    SYMBOL          INTENSITY CALL          VALUE
1     DDR1          2464.3023    P  0.00016023613
2     RFC2           496.5190    P   0.0193034606
3    HSPA6           733.4763    P   0.0008046637
4     PAX8          2138.2882    P   0.0005617505
5   GUCA1A           176.3272    A   0.1896873022
6     UBA7           729.6157    P   0.0170004527
7     DDR1          2464.3023    P   0.0016023613
8     RFC2           496.5190    P   0.0593034606
9    HSPA9           733.4763    P   0.0008046637
10    PAX8          2138.2882    P     0.15617505
11 GUCA1A2           176.3272    A  0.01896873022
12    UBA8           729.6157    P   0.0170004527
```

I used following to remove the duplicates. I kept the one with minimum "VALUE" in the fourth column.

```
dt <- data.table(df)   
WoDuplic <- dt[,.SD[which.min(VALUE)],by=list(SYMBOL)]
```

It serves the purpose, but is very slow, it takes approximatively 10 seconds to remove the duplicates from a data.frame of above dimension. Is there any way to make the process faster?

**Edited:** Output looks like

```
SYMBOL          INTENSITY CALL          VALUE
1     DDR1          2464.3023    P  0.00016023613
2     RFC2           496.5190    P   0.0193034606
3    HSPA6           733.4763    P   0.0008046637
4     PAX8          2138.2882    P   0.0005617505
5   GUCA1A           176.3272    A   0.1896873022
6     UBA7           729.6157    P   0.0170004527


9    HSPA9           733.4763    P   0.0008046637

11 GUCA1A2           176.3272    A  0.01896873022
12    UBA8           729.6157    P   0.0170004527
```

Comment: So they are only duplicates wrt the first 3 columns, is that right?

Comment: @jbaums Not necessary with all, but always wrt first column

Comment: How about `setorder(dt, VALUE); dt[!duplicated(SYMBOL)]`?

Comment: So you want to delete rows that are identical to other rows? Is that it?

Comment: @maRtin I want to delete, but want to keep only one which has minimum entry  in `VALUE` column

Comment: Try `.I` which would be faster.  `dt[dt[,.I[which.min(VALUE)],by=list(SYMBOL)]$V1]`

Comment: Or maybe `setkey(dt, VALUE); dt[, .SD[1L], by = SYMBOL]`

Comment: @akrun . Please make this as an answer. May i know how it works.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Is it faster compared to the `.I`?

Comment: @AaghazHussain I think the `setkey` might be a bit more faster, though I am not sure whether `.SD` slows it

Comment: @akrun I have no idea as I haven't benchmarked. It's biggest advantage over your solution is that it doesn't have the `which.min` overhead, but I don't know how would it scale. In theory we could combine both solutions and combine `.I` and `setkey` and `1L`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Consider to post your solution

Comment: @akrun  Your posted :                                                                                                user  system elapsed 
  1.896   0.008   1.897 for 4 files of 50000 rows

Comment: @AaghazHussain how `setkey(dt, VALUE) ; indx <- dt[,.I[1L], by = SYMBOL]$V1 ; dt[indx]` scales?

Comment: Huh? Very strange. @akrun I guess you should post it as your solution works best for the OP.

Comment: @DavidArenburg for the example showed, your solution and the docendodiscimus solution worked for me

Comment: @akrun don't know where i am going wrong. It gives same for docensodiscimus and DavidArenburg post

Comment: @akrun oh I didn't see his solution. That would the fastest one for sure. Also `setorder(dt, VALUE); unique(dt, by = "SYMBOL")` should be ultra fast. I guess OP has some old/corrupted `data.table` version

Comment: @AaghazHussain what is your `data.table` version? I think it is either old or corrupted. @docendodiscimus solution or using `unique` will be the fastest by far.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Please check my post down for time take by your code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could get the index of rows (`.I[which.min(..)`) that have minimum 'VALUE' for each 'SYMBOL' and use that column ('V1') to subset the dataset.

```
library(data.table)
dt[dt[,.I[which.min(VALUE)],by=list(SYMBOL)]$V1]
```

Or as @DavidArenburg mentioned, using `setkey` would be more efficient (although I am not sure why you get error with the original data)

```
 setkey(dt, VALUE) 
 indx <- dt[,.I[1L], by = SYMBOL]$V1 
 dt[indx]
```

Comment: I think worth including `unique` and `duplicated` as these both would be the fastest for sure. I think that `setkey(dt, VALUE) ; indx <- dt[,.I[1L], by = SYMBOL]$V1 ; dt[indx]` would be also faster.

Comment: `system.time({WoDuplic <- dt[dt[,.I[which.min(VALUE)],by=list(SYMBOL)]$V1]})`
   `user  system elapsed 
  0.124   0.000   0.123 `
`system.time({WoDuplic <- setkey(dt, VALUE); dt[, .SD[1L], by = SYMBOL]})`
   user  system elapsed 
  `0.312   0.004   0.314`

Comment: @AaghazHussain I guess the `setkey` will be faster if you execute it the 2nd time

Comment: @akrun it doesn't matter really I guess, as both of these runs less than a second. Either Way, the *really* fast solutions don't work for him for some awkward reason. My guess OP has some very old `data.table` version.

Comment: @akrun for second time your's                                                                              `user  system elapsed 
  0.124   0.000   0.124 `and David's                                                                   `user  system elapsed 
  0.308   0.000   0.308`

Comment: @AaghazHussain  Thanks for showing the time.  I guess this would be still some improvement to your original solution timings, right?.  Also, as DavidArenburg mentioned, try to install the latest version and see if the `setorder` `duplicated` solution work

Comment: @DavidArenburg  sory i missed your  updated code  `setkey(dt, VALUE) ; indx <- dt[,.I[1L], by = SYMBOL]$V1 ; dt[indx]`  user  system elapsed 
  0.012   0.000   0.014

Comment: @DavidArenburg Indeed your method is fast , and it changes `VALUE` format like this `4.430553e-05, 4.430553e-05 `. But i want the above formate

Comment: @AaghazHussain Try setting the `options`. i.e. `options(digits=20)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg . may i know what `[1L]` mean.

Comment: @AaghazHussain It is selecting the first observation.  By using `L` suffix we convert that to 'integer' class which may be a bit faster.  In the case of `.I[1L]` we get the position (row number) of the first observation for each group of SYMBOL

Comment: @akrun The main idea here is to keep the minimum value and remove other duplicates. How it works to keep the minimum, and if i need to keep maximum and remove other duplicates, how should it go.

Comment: @AaghazHussain  We are ordering by value column with `setkey(dt, VALUE)`. So the data is already sorted, now we need to select only the first row per each SYMBOL to get the min value

Comment: @akrun Thanks, as i see `setkey()` sorts in ascending order. is descending order supported, which i didn't  not find in `setkey()`.

Comment: @AaghazHussain  You need the min value so the ascending order is the one that is needed.  For descendng order, you may need to use `order`

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate and merge to solve the problem. It should be very fast.

create an example data.frame

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(gene=rep(letters[1:20],2500),INTENSITY=1:50000,value=runif(50000))
```

get the min value for each gene

```
mins <- aggregate(value ~ gene, data = df, FUN = min)
```

and merge the additional columns

```
df.min <- merge(mins, df)
```

Comment: I guess this should be very slow compared to the OP's method